# Swift - addTarget to UIButton inside a Subview

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subview

I have a problem with my `UIButton`. Just for basic understanding:

1. User taps on a button -> `popUpView` appears (`UIView`)
2. User taps on `UIButton` which is a SubView of `popUpView` -> `popUpView` dismisses

That is my code for that:

```
    @objc func addWishButtonTapped(notification : Notification){
    
    view.addSubview(popUpView)
    
    popUpView.addSubview(popUpTextField)
    popUpView.addSubview(wishButton)
    
    
    // constrain popUpView
    popUpView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    popUpView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    popUpView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    popUpView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 85).isActive = true
    
    // constrain wishButton
    wishButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    wishButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerYAnchor, constant: 130).isActive = true
    wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    // constrain textField
    popUpTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    popUpTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerYAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
    popUpTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    popUpTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 170).isActive = true

    popUpView.transform =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    popUpView.alpha = 0
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.visualEffectView.alpha = 1
        self.popUpView.alpha = 1
        self.popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
    
    // make whishButton clickable
    self.wishButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wishButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func wishButtonTapped(){
    print("test")
    insertWhish()
    dismissPopUpView()
}
```

**Problem:**

`whishButton` is not clickable and I have no idea why.. I'm stuck on this for a while now so I am grateful for any help, thanks :)

***UPDATE***

This is my View Hierarchy:

[image]

Really weird, because the selected `UIImage` should actually be the `UIButton` which is in my case behind it (100x100 square). I definitely declared my `whishButton` as an actual `UIButton()`

Comment: Do you check the hierarchy of views?

Comment: @Sammy not working :/

Comment: @AndresGomez what exactly do you mean by that ?:)

Comment: @DieGlueckswurst Xcode can show you this hierarchy, check this article (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) and tell me if your button is behind some view.

Comment: @AndresGomez I actually never used the debugger, I am quite new to this sorry, but I will try :)

Comment: ok got it. But it's very weird. It says that my `UIButton` is actually behind an `UIImage` which is the image I set the background to. But I why is that???

Answer (score 0):

first, try whit this line

```
self.popUpView.bringSubviewToFront(whishButton)
```

and if its necessary try this line

```
self.popUpView.sendSubview(yourImageBackGround)
```

Comment: Not working. What I found out was, I placed the `Button` below my `popUpView` (outside of it) but on purpose. If I place it inside of it, the button is clickable. Any idea why that happens and how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move buttons in storyboard
[image]

Comment: I do everything programmatically

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED***

I solved my problem.. not in a very smooth way but it's working now. I just added the `button` as another `subview` of my normal `UIView` instead of adding it within my `popUpView`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you don't create any instantiate of your root class globally.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewController: MyViewController
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        myViewController =storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MyViewController") as! MyViewController
        self.present(myViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
        myViewController.addWishButtonTapped(nil)
    }
}


class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let popUpView = UIView()
    let popUpTextField = UITextField()
    let wishButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @objc func addWishButtonTapped(notification : Notification?){
        view.addSubview(popUpView)

        popUpView.addSubview(popUpTextField)
        popUpView.addSubview(wishButton)


        // constrain popUpView
        popUpView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        popUpView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
        popUpView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        popUpView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 85).isActive = true

        // constrain wishButton
        wishButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        wishButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerYAnchor, constant: 130).isActive = true
        wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        // constrain textField
        popUpTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        popUpTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpView.centerYAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        popUpTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        popUpTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 170).isActive = true

        popUpView.transform =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        popUpView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.visualEffectView.alpha = 1
            self.popUpView.alpha = 1
            self.popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }

        // make whishButton clickable
        self.wishButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wishButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func wishButtonTapped(){
        print("test")
        insertWhish()
        dismissPopUpView()
    }
}
```